# UML diagram, Use case diagram

Tags: wordpress, drupal, developer, issues, civicrm-home

I am in need of Use-Case diagram, UML diagrams for CiviCRM. Not because I am very much need of them to use CiviCRM. just to show something in my presentation to my management :) !! . Any pointers would help .

(ER diagram different from UML/Use case diagrams)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ER diagram for the latest Civicrm , Foreign key in Structure, test cases/plans](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19704/er-diagram-for-the-latest-civicrm-foreign-key-in-structure-test-cases-plans)

Comment: This is the same as [the other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19704/er-diagram-for-the-latest-civicrm-foreign-key-in-structure-test-cases-plans) you asked.  You can use one of the tools Sean mentioned to generate a UML diagram; none currently exists.

Comment: ER diagram different from UML/Use case diagrams